Query fails to retrieve data, getting "Failed to get variables", "select query processing: line 1:34 mismatched character 'd' expecting '$'"
I have an issue. I want to visualize my data in Cassandra with Grafana. I made the connection and created a dashboard. I created 2 variables in this dashboard. These are devices and entity. I wrote the query for both.
I want the entity query to run according to the selected device data and to receive the appropriate entity data. device is arriving correctly, but my entity data is constantly Templating [entity]. I am getting:
Error updating options: Unexpected end of JSON input

Below is the query I wrote for variables:
devices: SELECT table_name FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name = 'orion_wins';
entity: SELECT entity_id FROM orion_wins.$devices WHERE entity_type='iot';
grafana log error: level=error msg="Failed to get variables" Message="repo.Select: select query processing: line 1:34 mismatched character 'd' expecting '$'"
When I run the query in the Cassandra terminal, I get the correct results. I have no problems with the query. Whatever the problem may be, I would be very happy if you could help me.

Seems like substitution either didn't happen, or resulted in something not expected. Create a second text variable and paste query from entity into it, so see how the query actually looks after substitution. If it looks right - check it in the Cassandra's console.

The symptom you described indicates that the variable $devices in:
SELECT entity_id FROM orion_wins.$devices WHERE entity_type='iot'

doesn't expand to the actual table name so the CQL parser flags it as an invalid statement.
In CQL, string literals are enclosed in single quotation marks (') much like in your query entity_type='iot'. But if the string contains a ' like Alice's wonderland (for example) then the dollar signs $$ can be used as escape characters like my_text = $$Alice's wonderland$$.
In your app, it appears the table name was not substituted for $devices so the query literally contains orion_wins.$devices. The error message:
... mismatched character 'd' expecting '$'

got returned because the CQL parser expects two dollar signs $$ instead of $d.
In any case, you need to review your code to determine why it failed to do expansion.
As a side note, your application appears to be doing the same thing as the Cassandra Datasource for Grafana project by Aleks Volochnev. It allows you to easily integrate Grafana so you can visualise time-series data that is stored in Cassandra. Cheers!
